# Carrierwave - File not removed automatically when changing upload directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm using Carrierwave for file upload in my Rails app.

I followed the [How-To Secure Upload guide](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-To:-Secure-Upload) to secure my uploads. It works perfectly, but the uploaded file is not removed when it's owner (the model using the uploader) is destroyed. I get no error messages, the file is just left where it was uploaded.

I tried changing it back to upload files to `public/uploads` and files are removed as they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer myself. I had restarted my webbserver after chancing upload directory so the file got uploaded to the correct directory. But I removed the model from Rails console, and I hadn't restarted the console after changing the upload directory.